# Chip text is empty even after setText

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-chips

> Chip.getText().toString() is empty even after calling chip.setText()

I have debugged and test even after calling `chip.setText("any Dummy Text")` . But when I **evaluate while debugging** `chip.getText().toString()`. It is empty even after the next line of setting text

**SourceCode**

```
for (TagBO tagItem : tagBOS) {
            final Chip newChip = new Chip(Favourite_Tag.this);
            newChip.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            newChip.setChipDrawable(ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(Favourite_Tag.this, null,
                    0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Filter));
            newChip.setText(tagItem.getTagName()); 
            newChip.setId(num); 
            // even after setting text I debug it here like newChip.getText().toString()

            newChip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (!categories_Selected.contains(newChip.getText().toString())) {  // getText().toString() is "" 
                        categories_Selected.add(newChip.getText().toString());
                       // Toast.makeText(Favourite_Tag.this, ""+, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        categories_Selected.remove(newChip.getText().toString());
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Favourite_Tag.this, ""+newChip.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   // model.updateCategoryFireStore(categories_Selected);
                }
            });
    }
```

**Issue Resolved**

After upgrading to `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02` issue resolved

Comment: Which version of material components are you using and what is num?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks for the suggestion.  It is a library version issue

Comment: have you checked tagItem.getTagName() is not empty?